# Record audio from an audio stream

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I'm building an app that plays audio streams. Below is the code I have.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var player: AVPlayer!
    private var kvoContext: UInt8 = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Streaming
        let streamURL = NSURL(string: "http://adsl.ranfm.lk/")!
        player = AVPlayer(URL: streamURL)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapPlayButton(sender: UIButton) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidReachEnd(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: &kvoContext)

        player.play()
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &kvoContext {
            print("Change at \(keyPath) for \(object)")
        }

        if player.status == .Failed {
            print("AVPlayer Failed")
        }

        if player.status == .ReadyToPlay {
            print("Ready to play")
            player.play()
        }

        if player.status == .Unknown {
            print("AVPlayer Unknown")
        }
    }

    func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Reached the end of file")
    }
}
```

This plays the stream successfully. Now I want to add the ability to record the audio from this stream.

Based on what I could find, the `AVAudioRecorder` class is only for recording audio through the microphone. Is there a way to record audio from a stream?

Comment: @KiritModi This is to record audio from the device's microphone, right? I need to record from an audio stream.

Comment: :Did you solve this problem?